# How to disable copy in shared folder

Tags: windows-xp, copy-protection

I am trying to make folder that everyone can view and can't copy,modify.

---

For all answers.I thinking about specially ms office files.
I tried following methods

```
Software
 - copy protect  
 - anti copy
   This method can't protect save as and upload

MS office macro
   Users can enable,disable macros.

MS office restriction
   This is best choice but can't protect from file uploading.
```

Almost I found the solution. Way is combination of MS office restriction and restrict access from browsers using firewall or antivirus. But I don't exact how to do this.

Comment: You can't control what another system does with data you give it. All you can control is what data you give it.

Answer (score 10):

Read only access means that they cannot modify the files in place, but can view them.  Because they can view, they can copy, and modify that copy, but they cannot put the modified copy back on the share if it is read-only.  There isn't any way around this.

Imagine it was a word document - read permissions provides the access to open the file in Word, but obviously there can't be a mechanism to stop them Saving As.

Answer (score 10):

Ask the RIAA and MPAA how they're doing on this "read but not copy" issue with digital data.

Seriously, making data un-copyable is like making water not be wet.  Data is copied around your computer and transformed dozens of times just to display it to the screen, or output it to your speakers.

The more recent cracks of Apple's "FairPlay" DRM system involved intercepting the raw data during transformation, after it had been decrypted, but before it was sent to the speakers.

I hate to say it, but give up on this concept.  It's just not possible.