# How can I copy protect an executable file on a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, file-transfer, copy-protection

So I went through coding a python application, which I will put on a flash drive (maybe a few of them) and give it to a person, I'll probably use py2exe to convert it to an executable file as a way to hide the code up a bit (.exe), but here's the problem: I don't really trust these people and I'm not so sure they may use it elsewhere which I don't want so I thought I'd put it on a USB drive and try to get it to be protected somehow so they can use it but not copy, cut or delete it. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect file from copying](http://superuser.com/questions/916709/how-to-protect-file-from-copying), [How to disable copy in shared folder](http://superuser.com/questions/348592/how-to-disable-copy-in-shared-folder) ...

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know why you have chosen to go with a scripting language like Python if you want to hide things or restrict uses.

You should think about using a compiled language like: C/C++, Java,..etc. To secure program itself from reverse engineering, that's a board topic.

To make things hard on the user, I though about a different approach which I didn't try: *Use flash drive as dongle*.

- You program should check if the flash drive with this serial XXXXXX is connected.
- You can go far and check where it's launched, if it is the same storage media.