# How to make it difficult to copy content of a USB drive?

Tags: windows, usb

I have a video file in my USB drive. I am going to give it to many people. I do not want anyone of them to copy the content. I am searching a way to make the file 
I searched in Google. I came to know it is impossible to do.

So I don't want to make it impossible to copy. I just want to make it difficult. It should not be simple right click and copy OR drag and drop.

Is there any method to do that ?
(I assume the user is using Windows.)

Comment: Perhaps also see: [How can I copy protect an executable file on a USB flash drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/922016/how-can-i-copy-protect-an-executable-file-on-a-usb-flash-drive?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the easy way. Just set a password on it? You can also hide it, but if someone uses 'show hided folder' it won't work as a security.

but anyway, setting pass on it won't help in your case, because user can still copy it

You can prevent copying completely by adding some values in registry, but I don't know if you want this (just serach for "windows prevent from copying" regedit).